# When to use async vs defer when loading scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

So I've recently learned that putting your js at the bottom of the DOM is antiquated, and that I should be once again putting them in the `<head>` with the “async” and “defer” attributes.

Great. But I'm a bit confused as to which I should use, based on priority.

So I have:

- jquery
- jquery plugins that don't have immediate effects on the look of the
  page
- jquery plugins that do have immediate effects on the look of the page
- my own personal scripts, which have immediate effects on the look of
  the page, and is also reliant on jquery

Which should get async, and which should get defer?

If I understand all this correctly, the ones that don't have an immediate effect on the look of the site should get defer, while everything else gets async. Correct? Or am I getting these mixed up.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's quite simple. You should use `[async]` for scripts which can be executed in any order, and `[defer]` for scripts which have to be executed after HTML is parsed.

For example, if you have a script that add social sharing icons next to your posts, and this script doesn't rely on any other script, you can use both `[async]` and `[defer]`. But if your scripts requires jQuery, you can't use `[async]`, because if you do, it might turn out that it gets executed before jQuery is loaded and it breaks.

If all your scripts require jQuery, then you shouldn't use `[async]` at all. As for `[defer]`, it depends on whether your scripts access DOM. For plugins it probably doesn't matter, but you'll probably need it for your own code.

If you wrap your scripts in `$(document).ready();`, you can use `[defer]` for scripts which don't have immediate effect (e.g. require user interaction).

Comment: For DOM manipulation script what should i use . defer or async?

Comment: @Apoorv You should definitely use `[defer]`; as for `[async]`, it depends on whether execution order matters to you.

Comment: One of the best explanation so far from so many answers. Thanks @MichałPerłakowski

Comment: If you place scripts in the head don't you need to use `defer` in order to allow them to load without blocking the html page loading, irrespecitve of whether they need to access the DOM or not.

Comment: According to [MDN docs for the script tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) using `defer` prevents the firing of the `DOMContentLoaded` event. I'm wondering what are the risks of the JS not loading or loading slowly and preventing the initial load of the page?

Comment: @gabriel14 No, it says “Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the `DOMContentLoaded` event from firing _until the script has loaded and finished evaluating_.” That means that `DOMContentLoaded` will fire, but not yet.

Comment: @Manngo, thanks for correcting me, I worded that poorly. I'm still curious though: if a script fails to load, would that prevent `DOMContentLoaded`? I guess if it fails, the event would not be withheld, but it's only a guess